# How to append dictionary rows into empty pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe df and and empty dataframes df1 and df2.
I am trying to append rows if conditions are true in df1 or df2

```
##df is my input dataframe

#df1 and df2 are empty dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)


df_dict = df.to_dict('records')
for rows in df_dict:
     if condition1 == true:
       print(rows)
       df1.append(rows, ignore_index = True)

     else:
       print(rows)
       df2.append(rows, ignore_index = True)
```

print is returning rows but append is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign `df1` and `df2` again for it works, else the value of `df1` and `df2` will not be updated. Beside, you it must be `df1.append`, not `df1.appned`

```
##df is my input dataframe

#df1 and df2 are empty dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)


df_dict = df.to_dict('records')
for row in df_dict:
    if conditions1 == true:
        print(row)
        df1 = df1.append(row, ignore_index = True)
    else:
        print(row)
        df2 = df2.append(row, ignore_index = True)

print(df1)
```

Comment: obviously it was Typo

Comment: @Shubh it was typo, but you really need to assign `df1` again

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `append` cuz it is depreciated. Instead use `concat` will solve your problem. Also, you do not need to iterate by row

However, I see your problem is not that complicated. It is simply using `.loc`:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['col'] == condition, : ].copy()
df2 = df.loc[~(df['col'] == condition), : ].copy()
```

If `df1` and `df2` is **not** empty dataframe, and you want to add rows meeting condition to them:

```
tem1 = df.loc[df['col'] == condition, : ].copy()
tem2 = df.loc[~(df['col'] == condition), : ].copy()

# df1:
df1 = pd.concat([df1, tem1])

# df2:
df2 = pd.concat([df2, tem2])
```

Comment: if condition: append into df1, else append into df2 . This requires looping through ?

Comment: @Shubh: from your code, I understand that I can divide `df` into two groups. Group of rows that meet condition, call gr A, and group of rows not meet condition, call gr B. Instead of iterating each row (which takes a lot of time), you can use `.loc` to filter those rows that belong to group A (meet condition) as `df1` and group B (not meet condition) as `df2'. If I miss understand your question, please elaborate it a bit more.